# Wordpress theme installation error when trying to install a new theme

Tags: wordpress

A techy English teacher needs your help.

I just bought a new theme and am having issues installing it. I am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/content/35/10913335/html/wp-content/themes/tribe/inc/customizer.php on line 16

When I went into do the code and deleted line 16 it prompted me next there was an error in line 108. I delete that line too. I installed the theme, but it had hardly any of the customization options.

Any suggestions, or should I just ask for a refund and buy a different theme?

Comment: I guess you purchased the theme on themeforest. Try to download the theme again and try to install. Uninstall / clean the old theme first. 

Deleting line by line is not a solution.  Also please share the codes of customizer.php , so we can look into it. 

Finally check your hostings php version. If your php version is older then v5.3, then that might be a reason. Get your hosting upgrade to v5.6 or latest.

Comment: To riterate: @MashR. identified *multiple things to do*, and every single one of them is on point.  Follow them carefully *if you want to use this theme*.  It may just be a crap theme, and you actually should be asking for support from the theme author.

Comment: @cale_b , Thanks. I should have been more organized while suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

1) Uninstall the theme completely.

2) Download the theme again from source ( themeforest my guess ). Try to install again.

3) If you still see the error. [Check the php version](http://www.wikihow.com/Check-PHP-Version) of your server. If its php 5.3 or lower. Contact your hostings support and ask them to upgrade.

4) If upgrading to php does not solve your problem, share the codes of customizer.php with us.

5) Contact theme developer for support. Usually they take some time to reply.